# Cannot resolve symbol for my List using Json

Tags: java, list, android-studio, resolve

Below Im trying to create a list, however the symbol "Feed" cannot be resolved. What have I left out that should be included. The idea is to take news articles from a file I have created.

```
public class Utils {
    private static final String TAG = "Utils";
    public static List<Feed> loadFeeds(Context context){
        try{
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = builder.create();
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(loadJSONFromAsset(context, "news.json"));
            List<Feed> feedList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                Feed feed = gson.fromJson(array.getString(i), Feed.class);
                feedList.add(feed);
            }
            return feedList;
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG,"seedGames parseException " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context, String jsonFileName) {
        String json = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
            Log.d(TAG,"path "+jsonFileName);
            is = manager.open(jsonFileName);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create `List<Feed>`, you have to create class `Feed` and import it to your `Utils` class.